# PHP MySQL: Take highest values from multiple categories and write an array?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

I have a table of student scores.  Students can take the test multiple times, we only care about the highest score.

So the table looks something like this:

```
UserID      CatID       Score
20          5           60
20          5           85
20          5           80
20          6           90
20          7           80
20          7           75
20          7           90
22          5           75
22          5           85
```

Want to get back one row based on a UserID variable that looks like this:

```
UserID      Cat5        Cat6        Cat7
20              85          90          90
```

Here's what I'm using so far as a query:

```
SELECT score AS Score
, catid
FROM `quiz_result` 
WHERE userid=65 and catid=5
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Not sure how to get the other categories in one row...thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this piece:

```
SELECT catID, MAX( score ) FROM `quiz_result`
GROUP BY catID;
```

The output isn't exactly same as in your sample, but it pretty much gives what you need.

**EDIT**

Output will be like:

```
catID      MAX(score)
Cat5        85
Cat6        90
Cat7        90
```

To get other columns, just include their names in the SELECT query.

Comment: Thanks!  That gives me one category (which my query does also) - I need to get all the categories :/

Comment: @Gisto, its output will be like as shown in the `edited` post.

Comment: So it does!  I had a Limit in there so I didn't see the others - thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', catID) AS catID, CONCAT_WS(',', MAX(score)) FROM `quiz_result` GROUP BY catID;
```

Comment: Ahh, that worked too!  Sorry, saw @hjpotter92's first.  Also, got an error first time, I think it's supposed to be CONCAT_WS instead of WS_CONCAT if anyone else is looking.